# Problem with naming record fields for List data type

Tags: liquid-haskell

For the sake of demonstration, I have two nearly-identical files: `ListSuccess.hs` and `ListFailure.hs`:

```hs
-- File: ListSuccess.hs
module ListSuccess where


import           Prelude                 hiding ( head
                                                , tail
                                                )


{-@
data List a = Nil | Cons { lh :: a , lt :: List a }
@-}
data List a = Nil |Cons { lh :: a , lt :: List a }
```

```hs
-- File: ListFailure.hs
module ListFailure where


import           Prelude                 hiding ( head
                                                , tail
                                                )


{-@
data List a = Nil | Cons { head :: a , tail :: List a }
@-}
data List a = Nil | Cons { head :: a , tail :: List a }
```

The only difference between these files is that `ListSuccess` names the fields of `Cons` as `lh` and `lt`, and `ListFailure` names the fields of `Cons` as `head` and `tail`.

Compiling with `liquid`, `ListSuccess.hs` compiles successfully, however `ListFailure` fails to compile, yielding this error:

```
 10 | data List a = Nil | Cons { head :: a , tail :: List a }
           ^^^^^

     ListFailure.head :: forall a .
                         lq$recSel:(ListFailure.List a) -> {VV : a | VV == head lq$recSel}
     Sort Error in Refinement: {VV : a##xo | VV == head lq$recSel}
     Cannot unify fix$36$$91$$93$ with ListFailure.List in expression: head lq$recSel


 /Users/henry/Documents/Prototypes/liquidhaskell/list-fields-bug/ListFailure.hs:12:21-55: Error: Illegal type specification for `ListFailure.Cons`

 12 | data List a = Nil | Cons { head :: a , tail :: List a }
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

     ListFailure.Cons :: forall a .
                         head:a -> tail:(ListFailure.List a) -> {VV : (ListFailure.List a) | tail VV == tail
                                                                                             && head VV == head}
     Sort Error in Refinement: {VV : (ListFailure.List a##agi) | (tail VV == tail##ListFailure.Cons
                                                                  && head VV == head##ListFailure.Cons)}
     Cannot unify fix$36$$91$$93$ with ListFailure.List in expression: tail VV
```

As far as I can tell, using `head` and `tail` as the field names should not be an issue, especially because I imported prelude hiding those names. The same error occurs even when I use `import qualified Prelude` and similar variants.

Is this a bug, or is there something that I'm missing here?

Configuration:

- LiquidHaskell Version 0.8.6.0.